# matplotlib correlation matrix heatmap with grouped colors as labels

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, heatmap, correlation, axis-labels

I have a correlation matrix hat I am trying to visualize with matplotlib. I can create a heatmap style figure just fine, but I am running into problems with how I want the labels. I'm not even sure if this is possible, but this is what I'm trying to do and can't seem to make it work:

My correlation matrix is 150 X 150. On either the x or y (or both...this doesn't matter) axis, I would like to group the labels and then simply label them with a color, or a white label on a color background.

To clarify, let's say I'd like to have 1-15 as "Group 1" and either simply be a Blue bar, or "Group 1" text on a blue bar. Then 16-20 as "Group 2" on a red bar, or simply a red bar. Etc, through all of the items in the matrix.

I have been failing at both grouping axis labels as well as getting any color on them. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My code is below, though it's quite basic and I don't know if it will help.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

# COREELATION MATRIX TEST #
corr = np.genfromtxt(csv_path,delimiter=',')
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet', 30)
cax = ax1.imshow(corr, cmap=cmap)
ax1.grid(True)
plt.title('THIS IS MY TITLE')
fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=[-1,-0.8,-0.6,-0.4,-0.2,0.0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0])
plt.show()
```

Comment: How does the input data look and what is the grouping parameter? Please provide a [mcve] with some sample data and use it to explain how the plot should look like. Possibly a simple drawing of what you would like could also help to understand the desired plot.

Comment: I found a picture online that shows similar data and what I'd like to do: [link]https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Deanna_Greene/publication/292707637/figure/fig5/AS:324765710602248@1454441587613/Figure-1-Group-average-264-ROI264-ROI-correlation-matrices-show-the-expected-network.png)

In this example they have red lines and labels (such as "Default Mode" and "Visual"). I would like to group my variables in the same way, but instead of the red lines in the matrix, I'd rather the label just be a swatch of color.

Similar to the colorbar on the side, but with manually set colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create auxilary axes next to the plot and plot colored bar plots to them. Turning the axes spines off lets those bars look like labelboxes.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

# COREELATION MATRIX TEST #
corr = 2*np.random.rand(150,150)-1
# labels [start,end]
labels = np.array([[0,15],[16,36],[37,82],[83,111],[112,149]])
colors = ["crimson", "limegreen","gold","orchid","turquoise"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

im = ax.imshow(corr, cmap="Blues")

ax.set_title('THIS IS MY TITLE')
fig.colorbar(im, ticks=[-1,-0.8,-0.6,-0.4,-0.2,0.0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0])

# create axes next to plot
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
axb = divider.append_axes("bottom", "10%", pad=0.06, sharex=ax)
axl = divider.append_axes("left", "10%", pad=0.06, sharey=ax)
axb.invert_yaxis()
axl.invert_xaxis()
axb.axis("off")
axl.axis("off")


# plot colored bar plots to the axes
barkw = dict( color=colors, linewidth=0.72, ec="k", clip_on=False, align='edge',)
axb.bar(labels[:,0],np.ones(len(labels)), 
        width=np.diff(labels, axis=1).flatten(), **barkw)
axl.barh(labels[:,0],np.ones(len(labels)), 
         height=np.diff(labels, axis=1).flatten(), **barkw)

# set margins to zero again
ax.margins(0)
ax.tick_params(axis="both", bottom=0, left=0, labelbottom=0,labelleft=0)
# Label the boxes
textkw = dict(ha="center", va="center", fontsize="small")
for k,l in labels:
    axb.text((k+l)/2.,0.5, "{}-{}".format(k,l), **textkw)
    axl.text(0.5,(k+l)/2., "{}-{}".format(k,l), rotation=-90,**textkw)

plt.show()
```