# How to add horizontal lines as annotations (outside of axes) in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting a bar chart using seaborn and matplotlib. I would like to annotate the plot with both words and a line.

Here is my strategy for generating the figure (apologies for providing `plot_data` but it is rather large):

```
        plt.figure()
        ax = seaborn.barplot(x='cell_line', y='DeltaCt', data=plot_data, hue='time')
        plt.title('Baseline: {}'.format(g))
        plt.ylabel('DeltaCt')
        plt.xlabel('')
        trans = ax.get_xaxis_transform()
        ax.annotate('Neonatal', xy=(0.4, -0.1), xycoords=trans)
        plt.show()
```

which generates:
[image]

However I need another black line on this plot between the x-axis and the 'Neonatal' annotation. Like this:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some related questions:

- [Multiple lines of x tick labels in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532614/multiple-lines-of-x-tick-labels-in-matplotlib)
- [How to add group labels for bar charts in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184484/how-to-add-group-labels-for-bar-charts-in-matplotlib)
- [matplotlib correlation matrix heatmap with grouped colors as labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46507472/matplotlib-correlation-matrix-heatmap-with-grouped-colors-as-labels)
- [How to add hierarchical axis across subplots in order to label groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44484391/how-to-add-hierarchical-axis-across-subplots-in-order-to-label-groups)

Here you want a vertical line, but that line would need to be in data coordinates along the x axis. Hence you can use the `ax.get_xaxis_transform()`. To make the line visible outside the axes use `clip_on = False`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plot_data = pd.DataFrame({"cell_line": np.random.choice(list("ABCDEFG"), size=150),
                          'DeltaCt' : np.random.rayleigh(5,size=150),
                          "time":np.random.choice([0,96], size=150)})

plt.figure()
ax = sns.barplot(x='cell_line', y='DeltaCt', data=plot_data, hue='time', 
                 order=list("ABCDEFG"))
plt.title('Baseline: {}'.format("H"))
plt.ylabel('DeltaCt')
plt.xlabel('')
trans = ax.get_xaxis_transform()
ax.annotate('Neonatal', xy=(1, -.1), xycoords=trans, ha="center", va="top")
ax.plot([-.4,2.4],[-.08,-.08], color="k", transform=trans, clip_on=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]